# Cannot read property of undefined inside the row expansion

Tags: angular, primeng

Befote I wrote this question I checked most of similar cases to mine, but with no success. I'm trying to display `number` and `auth` inside expandable row - I'm using PrimeNG. No matter what I try, nothing works. Since I'm out of fuel for this problem I need your help.

Simplified code:

**JSON**

```
{
"status": 0,
"dallases": [{
    "vehicle_id": 17954,
    "dallassettings": "3",
    "dallasupdated": "False",
    "dallas_list": [{
        "number": 666111222,
        "auth": 3
    }, {
        "number": 666777888,
        "auth": 4
    }, {
        "number": 123454321,
        "auth": 4
    }]
}
}
```

**Service**

```
export class VehicleService {
    private defUrl = 'dummy.url';

constructor(private http: Http) { }
getVehicle(username?: string, password?: string) {
    const url = (!username || !password) ? this.defUrl : 'dummy.url' + username + '/' + Md5.hashStr(password);
    return this.http.get(url)
        .map(res => res.json());
```

**Component**

```
export class VehicleComponent implements OnInit {

  cols: any[];

  ngOnInit() {
    this.cols = [
      { field: 'vehicle_id', header: "Vehicle ID" },
      { field: 'dallassettings', header: 'Dallas settings' },
      { field: 'dallasupdated', header: 'Dallas updated' },
      { field: 'dallas_list', header: 'Dallas list' }
    ];

  public vehicles: GeneralVehicle[];

  constructor(private vehicleService: VehicleService, private router: Router) {
    this.vehicleService.getVehicle().subscribe(vehicle => {
      this.vehicles = vehicle;
    });
  }

interface GeneralVehicle {
  status: number;
  dallases: Vehicle[];
}

interface Vehicle {
  vehicle_id: number;
  dallassettings: string;
  dallasupdated: string;
  dallas_list: DallasList[];
}

interface DallasList {
  number: number;
  auth: number;
}
```

**Template**

```
<div *ngIf="vehicles">
    <p-dataTable [value]="vehicles.dallases" expandableRows="true">
        <p-header>List of vehicles: <b>{{currentUser}}</b></p-header>
        <p-column expander="true" styleClass="col-icon"></p-column>
        <p-column field="vehicle_id" header="Vehicle ID" [sortable]="true"></p-column>
        <p-column field="dallassettings" header="Dallas settings" [sortable]="true"></p-column>
        <p-column field="dallasupdated" header="Dallas updated" [sortable]="true"></p-column>
        <ng-template let-vehicle="value.dallas_list" pTemplate="rowexpansion"> <!-- the problem is here -->
            <div class="ui-grid ui-grid-responsive ui-fluid" style="font-size:16px;padding:20px">
                <div class="ui-grid-row">
                    <div class="ui-grid-col-9">
                        <div class="ui-grid ui-grid-responsive ui-grid-pad">
                            <div class="ui-grid-row">
                                <div class="ui-grid-col-2 label">Number: </div>
                                <div class="ui-grid-col-10">{{dallas_list.number}}</div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="ui-grid-row">
                                <div class="ui-grid-col-2 label">Auth: </div>
                                <div class="ui-grid-col-10">{{dallas_list.auth}}</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </ng-template>
    </p-dataTable>
</div>
```

I'm expecting to be able to display all `number`s and `auth`s for each of the rows inside the expendable row.

Comment: Have you tried pulling the data inside ngOnInit? You usually want to use the constructor to setup dependency injection and nothing else. I am not sure that's related here but worth a try.

Comment: I'll give it a shot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not using ng-template variable correctly:

```
 <div *ngIf="vehicles">
    <p-dataTable [value]="vehicles.dallases" expandableRows="true">
        <p-header>List of vehicles: <b>{{currentUser}}</b></p-header>
        <p-column expander="true" styleClass="col-icon"></p-column>
        <p-column field="vehicle_id" header="Vehicle ID" [sortable]="true"></p-column>
        <p-column field="dallassettings" header="Dallas settings" [sortable]="true"></p-column>
        <p-column field="dallasupdated" header="Dallas updated" [sortable]="true"></p-column>
        <ng-template let-vehicle pTemplate="rowexpansion"> <!-- the problem is here -->
            <div class="ui-grid ui-grid-responsive ui-fluid" style="font-size:16px;padding:20px">
                <div class="ui-grid-row">
                    <div class="ui-grid-col-9">
                        <div class="ui-grid ui-grid-responsive ui-grid-pad" *ngFor="let list of vehicle.dallas_list">
                            <div class="ui-grid-row">
                                <div class="ui-grid-col-2 label">Number: </div>
                                <div class="ui-grid-col-10">{{list.number}}</div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="ui-grid-row">
                                <div class="ui-grid-col-2 label">Auth: </div>
                                <div class="ui-grid-col-10">{{list.auth}}</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </ng-template>
    </p-dataTable>
```

**Edit**

The changes were made inside `ng-template`. `let-vehicle` is a reference to the current item in the iteration of the rows done by PrimeNG.
Previously it was `let-vehicle="value.dallas_list"`. This was wrong since that was reference to the whole list. You need only one as said before.

Than `*ngFor` was added to `<div class="ui-grid ui-grid-responsive ui-grid-pad" *ngFor="let list of vehicle.dallas_list">` to iterate through current `dallas_list` and print `list.number` and `list.auth` inside html:

```
<div class="ui-grid ui-grid-responsive ui-grid-pad" *ngFor="let list of vehicle.dallas_list">
 <div class="ui-grid-row">
        <div class="ui-grid-col-2 label">Number: </div>
        <div class="ui-grid-col-10">{{list.number}}</div>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-grid-row">
        <div class="ui-grid-col-2 label">Auth: </div>
        <div class="ui-grid-col-10">{{list.auth}}</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: To improve your answer, I would suggest you point out where the error is and how you have changed it. Because now there is plenty code and hard to tell what changes you have made. Just a suggestion :)

Comment: This solution is working as intended. It just need some styling and will be perfectly fine. Thank you!

Comment: Glad it helped. @AJT_82 I edited to highlight the solution

Comment: @MarioPetrovic Nice, it's instantly a more clear answer, +1 for that! :)

Comment: Yes, you were right :D thanks for pointing that out for my further answers

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what exactly you want and I don't know anything about dataTable.

Try following things,

```
/* don't know if this is relevant or not */
<ng-template let-vehicle [ngForOf]="value.dallas_list"  pTemplate="rowexpansion">
  <li> {{vehicle.number}}</li>
  <li> {{vehicle.auth}}</li>
</ng-template>
```

**OR**

in your existing code access the element by its index number,

```
<div class="ui-grid-col-10">{{dallas_list[0].number}}</div>  //added [0]
```